# NHibernate : How to retrieve the data from IQuery.List() using field name?

Tags: nhibernate

My Query will be something like:

```
string query = " select a.CustomerName , b.ProductName from Customer as a join a.Product as b " 

IQuery query = applicationSession.CreateQuery(query);
IList listResult = query.List();
```

This will return the customer names and product names.
But what I want to do is something like:

```
string customerName = listResult[0]["CustomerName"];
string productName = listResult[0]["ProductName"];
```

Could anyone give me a help on how I can make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply a transformer to Hashtable:

```
string query = "select a.CustomerName as CustomerName, b.ProductName as ProductName from Customer as a join a.Product as b" 

IQuery query = applicationSession.CreateQuery(query);
var listResult = query.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToEntityMap).List<Hashtable>();


string customerName = (string)listResult[0]["CustomerName"];
string productName  = (string)listResult[0]["ProductName"];
```

Please note that I added aliases to your original query to make the AliasToEntityMap working.